# Copy a single large file (>100 MB)using the manual CreateFile()

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I want to copy a single file, fairly large (+100MB) using CreateFile(), ReadFile(), and WriteFile().

My program successfully copied text file and other small file (in the range of KBs), but when I wanted to copy a 160 single .EXE file, it crashed and the debugger said "Stack overflow"

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of your code here?

Comment: Sir the problem I've is with the size, I mean I wanna move a single 160MB at once. I'm using only CreateFile and WriteFile.

Comment: I tried to use malloc. But I'm not familiar with it, or it won't function in my program.

Comment: You've tagged your question C++. That means you don't need malloc(). First call `GetFileSize()`, then read the entire file into a `std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(fileSize)`.

Comment: I'll try that thanks, when I asked the guy who gave me the task, he said; "the solution is basic, you've a limitation in buffer and a large file, what would you do?"

Comment: *'and the debugger said "Stack overflow"'* Wow! Even debuggers know about this site by now...nice of it to tell you where to go.

Answer (score 5):

Don't read the whole file at once, read it in smaller chunks (up to a few megabytes) instead.

Windows has several file copy functions that are already quite flexible, e.g. `CopyFileEx`, so consider using one of these functions instead.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use CopyFile(), I know it can make the thing a lot easier. Just wanna use CreateFile() and WriteFile().

How do you suggest I break it in smaller chunks?

Comment: @Saif Why do you think that you can write it easier? Existing library code is typically well tested and optimized.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just have this assignment. I need to do it manually. :S

Comment: Remember to use dynamic memory (a.k.a. heap) for large buffers as the local (stack) and global memory have smaller size limits assigned by the compiler.

Comment: Yeah I read about this heap thing, I'll try to dig deeper into it and see what's what.Thank you Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler the better:
    int rc = system("copy foo.bin bar.bin");

Comment: Somebody could argue that in this way you completely loose control over the copy operation.

Comment: And it's invoking a shell, adding unnecessary conceptual overhead.

Comment: @Gianluca, copying a file is copying a file. What kind of control do you need ? Moreover, this is bug free.
@Philipp, what is a conceptual overhead ? Do you mean performance ?

Comment: For instance, you may want to display a progress bar. A very good practice when performing long processing within a GUI application